# asp.net: Create Handles clause for control class

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way that I force all TextBoxes (as an example) .. on an asp.net form, to go through the same routine, during a "postback" event or onchange event?

Comment: You can create a custom control base on TextBoxes and do that. You can also capture the post back on Init and check if its TextBox and onchange event and also run yours checks.

Comment: Thank you.. but you do have any examples or code ?

Comment: Search on the internet, there many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
            textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);          
        }
    }

    protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```